# Reading all Values in Row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, row

I want to read out all values in the header searching for a defined value

```
For i_col = column_a To column_z
 Set search = Wks1.Cells(i_col&"1")
 If search.Value = "" Then
```

So I saw possibilities like creating an array or tranpose all, but I'm searching for an easier way

I think this was frequendly asked, but I didn't found a good solution

Comment: remove the `set` keyword. it is used for objects, not for string values and numeric values

Comment: "What do you mean by "read out" ? If you are trying to Find or Match a value then there is Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel)  and Application.WorksheetFunction.Find (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-find-method-excel)

Comment: `Wks1.Cells(1, row_1)`

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use FIND method like below without using a loop:

`set rngSearch = Wks1.Range("A1:Z1").Find("WhatYouAreLookingFor",Wks1.Range("A1"),xlValues,xlWhole)`

Then you can test if it contains the desired value or not by using

`If Not rngSearch is nothing then`

Answer (score 0):

```
Set search = Wks1.Cells(i_col&"1")
If search.Value = "" Then
```

Too tired...
Of course, "search" is a range object, that's why the code works with
    'Set' and 'Search.Value'

I changed the code a bit

Sorry for that

@Shrivallabha Redij - this might work, yeah